# Preloader mp4 video is not responsive on my html page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to set mp4 video in my pre-loader of my web page but I am facing two issues to achieve this target.
[1:My video is not responsive and behave as its behave without html page, I mean by default video is responsive when I shrink or expand video size it occupy all space according to screen variation but when I load this video on my html page it is not responsive.

1:My video is not responsive and behave as its behave without html page, I mean by default video is responsive when I shrink or expand video size it occupy all space according to screen variation but when I load this video on my html page it is not responsive.
2:It does not run another header element or show header after playing the video.
Expectations:
I want to play the the video first when the page load then show other content on the page.
Secondly video should behave as original.
Here is my code
//index.html

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Your Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Preloader Container -->
  <div id="preloader-container">
    <video autoplay muted loop id="preloader-video">
      <source src="preloader.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
  </div>

  <header>Hello World</header>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

//styles.css

```
/* styles.css */
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden; /* Prevent scrolling during preloading */
}

#preloader-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #fff; /* Background color for the preloader */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 9999; /* Ensure the preloader is on top of other elements */
}

#preloader-container video {
  width: 100%; /* Make the video width cover the container */
  height: 100%; /* Make the video height cover the container */
  object-fit: cover; /* Maintain the video aspect ratio while covering the entire container */
  

}
```

script.js

```
// script.js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var preloaderVideo = document.getElementById("preloader-video");

  if (preloaderVideo) {
    // Reset video playback to the beginning when the page is loaded or refreshed
    preloaderVideo.currentTime = 0;

    // Hide the preloader container after the video has played
    preloaderVideo.addEventListener("ended", function() {
      document.getElementById("preloader-container").style.display = "none";
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**change you code with this :**

```js
// script.js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var preloaderVideo = document.getElementById("preloader-video");

  if (preloaderVideo) {
    // Reset video playback to the beginning when the page is loaded or refreshed
    preloaderVideo.currentTime = 0;

    // Hide the preloader container after the video has played
    preloaderVideo.addEventListener("ended", function() {
      document.getElementById("preloader-container").style.display = "none";
    });
  }
});
```

```css
/* styles.css */
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#preloader-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #fff; /* Background color for the preloader */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 9999; /* Ensure the preloader is on top of other elements */
}

#preloader-container video {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto; /* Change height to auto to maintain the video's aspect ratio */
  max-height: 100%; /* Set max-height to 100% to prevent stretching on smaller screens */
  object-fit: cover; /* Maintain the video aspect ratio while covering the entire container */
}

header {
  /* Add styles for the header */
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Your Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Preloader Container -->
  <div id="preloader-container">
    <video autoplay muted loop id="preloader-video">
      <source src="https://storage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
  </div>

  <header>Hello World</header>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi my height is not set acording to screen size